# Hibernate error in create entity manger [ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V ]

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm using Hibernate as a provider for JPA in Java EE 6 and JBoss 7.1.1 Final. I searched for solutions but im new with hibernate and I don't fix the issue. Im getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.build(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:278)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:173)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:34)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:114)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             version="2.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_app"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="test"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Main class for test the connection with DB

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // ----- Creating Users

    EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
    t.begin();

    User usuario1 = new User();
    usuario1.setUser_Name("User1");
    usuario1.setUserMessage("Text example 1");
    em.persist(usuario1);

    User usuario2 = new User();
    usuario2.setUser_Name("User2");
    usuario2.setUser_Name("Text example 2");
    em.persist(usuario2);

    t.commit();

    em.close();
    emf.close();
}
```

}

My libs

http://imgur.com/eL2KRXk

My project folder structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mx5l.jpg

And finally my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>agenda5</groupId>
    <artifactId>agenda5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <hibernate-core.version>3.6.4.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.16</mysql-connector-java.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.6.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: so your JPA implementation jars are inconsistent. NoSuchMethodError has clear enough javadocs. Get jars that are consistent

Comment: All the jars installed in the project are installed via Maven, but I will fix the complete javadocs for the jars. 

I fix the problem creating a hibernate.cfg.xml. But now I have a new Exception:

`[PersistenceUnit: manager1] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory`

Comment: which is not part of JPA. so you're presumably no using JPA now

Comment: Is not necessary create hibernate.cfg.xml?

Im getting new Exception when I create it:

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: manager1] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory`

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: The chosen transaction strategy requires access to the JTA TransactionManager`

Answer (score -1):

```
xml should be like the below
<persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_app</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property
                <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</property
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property
                <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property
                <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve any NoSuchMethodError ... which is down to what jars the user has in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Hi I hope by looking into the following statement,Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.verifyProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)V. It seems to be clear that while loading the perstance.xml file by org.hibernate.Configuration class, it found the definition of the xml is incorrect. if you could see the jar files the hibernate-core.jar it self contains .class file for org.hibernate.Configuration class. see the api @grepcode.com

Comment: Okay, and what is the solution?

Comment: format your persistance.xml file as above  suggested and then re-build your application then check once. it should work.

Comment: I fix the problem, but how can I create tables with the entities?

Comment: you could use the tag as <mapping class="fully qualified path of your entity"/> or if you are using mapping files then use <mapping resource="path of hbm file"/> to generate the tables automatically by the ASTQueryTranslator of Hibernate known as Hibernate engine.this will use a class called EntityPersistors to persist the state of an object in to the RDMS as a table.

Comment: you could use the tag as <mapping class="fully qualified path of your entity"/> or if you are using mapping files then use <mapping resource="path of hbm file"/> to generate the tables automatically by the ASTQueryTranslator of Hibernate known as Hibernate engine.this will use a class called EntityPersistors to persist the state of an object in to the RDMS as a table.